# Grant Privileges to Root via Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, remote-connection

Is there some way to grant all privileges to root via Dockerfile ou docker-compose.yml?
I'm trying to boot up a mysql:latest image like this:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
 services:
  mysql_database:
   container_name: mysql_test_server
   restart: always
   build: .
   image: mysql:latest
   command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   ports:
     - 3306:3306
   volumes:
     - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
     - ./config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

**dockerfile** (the build: . on .yml)

```
FROM mysql:latest
RUN mysql -u root -proot -h localhost -p 3306
RUN grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'root';
RUN flush all privileges;
RUN exit;
EXPOSE 3306
```

TLDR; I just want to grant privileges for remote connections (SQLYog, DBeaver, etc) automatically... if docker-compose up, run this command so I don't need to do manually, like `docker exet -it mysql_test_server mysql -u root ...`

I awalys get this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL server is not running in this docker file, so you are getting errors.

The default docker image has `root` user and `root` user has all privileges.

You have to use environment variables to achieve what you try to do:

Run this command:

```
docker run --name some-mysql \
    -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootPassword \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST="%" \
    -p 3306:3306 \
    -d mysql:tag
```

You have to replace paths in the `-v` parameter.

Then you can login to MySQL with command:

```
mysql -uroot -prootPassword -h127.0.0.1
```

The parameter you should take a look is `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST`. That variable is used in the `MySQL container entrypoint`: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L232-L239